# Images not showing up on some computers

Tags: html, css

[This](http://magic.cardbinder.com/) is my CSS for a concept I'm working on...

It displays the picture, and once you hover over the card it flips it. The problem I'm having is that it isn't working on SOME computers.  Oddly enough, it doesn't work on one of my computers.  It's windows XP.  It doesn't work in any of the modern browsers.  Another computer experienced it running OSX 10.5, and chrome.  The problem being, you only see the backwards text of the , then if flip to the normal view.

```
.sleeve {
  float: left;
  margin: 5px;
  width: 240px; height: 340px;
  perspective: 1000px;
  -webkit-perspective: 1000px;
  -moz-perspective: 1000px;
  -o-perspective: 1000px;   
}
.card {
  width: 240px;
  height: 340px;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
  -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
  -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
  -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-in;
}
.sleeve:hover .card {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  box-shadow: -5px 5px 5px #333333;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -webkit-box-shadow: -5px 5px 5px #333333;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-box-shadow: -5px 5px 5px #333333;
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-box-shadow: -5px 5px 5px #333333;
}
.face {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -moz-backface-visibility: hidden;
  -o-backface-visibility: hidden;
}
.face.front img {
  height: 340px;
  width: 240px;
  }
.face.back {
  display: block;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -o-transform: rotateY(180deg);
  -o-box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 5px solid #000000;
  padding: 5px 0 0 10px;
  height: 340px;
  width: 240px;
  overflow: auto;
  color: black;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #FFFFFF;
  }
```

If I add:

```
.face.front {
  z-index=10;
}
```

It shows the picture, but when it flips, the image is just backwards.

Comment: It works on Chrome 21 and FF 14 for me. You have a lot of css3 specific properties on there with vendor specific prefixes (-webkit-transform, -moz-transform, -o-transform). So its definitely not going to work in IE unless you add -ms-transform. You should also add the non specific -transform. Do this for all the properties you use with those specific prefixes and see if that helps. It should at least be working for most modern browsers with this. You'll likely never get it to work in older browsers using those properties.

Comment: yeah, I have chrome 21 here too, but it doesn't work.  That's the weird thing, is (from what I can tell) it's not browser specific.  Does CSS3 depend on certain forms of hardware acceleration?

Comment: Great thought. 3D transforms are usually hardware accelerated, yes. Now would probably be the time you have to decide how important it is that it's able to run on older hardware and browsers. If it is, then we'll likely need to come up with a different solution that possibly switches content out mid 2d transform or something to that effect.

Comment: I thought so... poo.  I'd like to think I want this to work on everyone's computer, but that's probably silly.  Considering I'm going with HTML5 and CSS3, I'm catering to the more modern crowd.  Could the same effect be created with javascript?

Comment: I believe so though I haven't looked into it. It'd be more work and less efficient for sure. I would look for a premade library that will handle it. If you're going with modern HTML5 and CSS3 techniques I'd drop the notion of support from older computers, especially things running XP with IE8 or lower. You'll save yourself multiple factors of debugging and implementation time as well as headaches. Sorry I couldn't be of more help.